# Incomplete types and initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to model some meta data for serializing/de-serializing C++ objects.  Here is something that captures the nuts & bolts of what I need; it compiles with GCC 5.2 (`g++ sample.cpp -std=c++14`) and with Clang 3.6 (`clang++ sample.cpp -std=c++14`).

My question is about the `struct TypeInfo` in the example.  It contains an `std::initializer_list` of itself.  Is this standards-conforming?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <initializer_list>

enum class TypeCode : std::uint8_t { BOOLEAN, INT, OBJECT, STRING, SENTINEL };

struct TypeInfo
{
    TypeCode typeCode_;

    char fieldName_[64];

    union
    {
        std::uint16_t textMinLength_;
        std::uint16_t objectVersionMajor_;
    };

    union
    {
        std::uint16_t textMaxLength_;
        std::uint16_t objectVersionMinor_;
    };

    //  set only if typeCode_ = OBJECT
    std::initializer_list < TypeInfo > objectTypeInfos_;
};

int main()
{
    TypeInfo const sti { TypeCode::STRING, "updatedBy", { .textMinLength_ = 0 }, { .textMaxLength_ = 16 } };

    TypeInfo const iti { TypeCode::INT, "amount", { 0 }, { 0 } };

    TypeInfo const oti { TypeCode::OBJECT, "startTime", { .objectVersionMajor_ = 1 }, { .objectVersionMinor_ = 0 }, {
      TypeInfo { TypeCode::INT, "weekdays", { 0 }, { 0 } },
      TypeInfo { TypeCode::INT, "timeOfDay", { 0 }, { 0 } },
      TypeInfo { TypeCode::STRING, "timezone", { .textMinLength_ = 0 }, { .textMaxLength_ = 5 } }
    } };

    TypeInfo const noti { TypeCode::OBJECT, "schedule", { .objectVersionMajor_ = 1 }, { .objectVersionMinor_ = 0 }, {
      TypeInfo { TypeCode::INT, "id", { 0 }, { 0 } },
      TypeInfo { TypeCode::STRING, "description", { .textMinLength_ = 0 }, { .textMaxLength_ = 16 } },
      TypeInfo { TypeCode::OBJECT, "startTime", { .objectVersionMajor_ = 1 }, { .objectVersionMinor_ = 0 }, {
        TypeInfo { TypeCode::INT, "weekdays", { 0 }, { 0 } },
        TypeInfo { TypeCode::INT, "timeOfDay", { 0 }, { 0 } },
        TypeInfo { TypeCode::STRING, "timezone", { .textMinLength_ = 0 }, { .textMaxLength_ = 5 } }
      } }
    } };
}
```

Comment: Are you sure a member `initializer_list` is valid? Per [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) (bold mine): _"The lifetime of the underlying array is the same as any other temporary object, except that initializing an initializer_list object from the array extends the lifetime of the array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary **(with the same exceptions, such as for initializing a non-static class member)**."_ By my reading, the `TypeInfo`s referred to by your `objectTypeInfos_` go out of scope after the constructor call, giving undefined behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That actually induces undefined behavior with current wording. At the point of instantiation of `std::initializer_list<TypeInfo>`, `TypeInfo` is incomplete, hence [res.on.functions]/(2.5) applies:

> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases: 
>  (2.5)
>   — if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when
>   instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for
>   that component.

… and incomplete types are not specifically allowed for `initializer_list` yet - however, that's clearly defective. LWG [**issue 2493**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2493) opts to fix this:

> The typical use-case of `std::initializer_list<T>` is for a
>   pass-by-value parameter of `T`'s constructor. However, this contravenes
>   [res.on.functions]/2.5 because initializer_list doesn't specifically
>   allow incomplete types (as do for example `std::unique_ptr`
>   ([unique.ptr]/5) and `std::enable_shared_from_this`
>   ([util.smartptr.enab]/2)).
>
> A resolution would be to copy-paste the relevant text from such a
>   paragraph.

I.e. your code is fine (and will be officially fine after resolution of the aforementioned DR).

Comment: ...at least assuming the DR is resolved as you apparently expect. No action has been taken since it was filed, so it could still be resolved as "NAD". I doubt that'll happen, but it's still not a given that it'll be resolved in favor of allowing incomplete types either.

Comment: @JerryCoffin This defect is completely justified and will be resolved accordingly. I can think of many, many reasonable examples which are currently UB for this very reason (e.g. stuff like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea23d84143def16f)). I don't see your point, sorry.

Comment: My point is simply that resolving the DR won't *necessarily* make this particular piece of code have defined behavior. Yes, it could be resolved by just adding a statement that `initializer_list` can be instantiated over an incomplete type. It could also be resolved in a more limited way that (for example) allows its instantiation over an incomplete type when being used as a parameter to a ctor, but still exclude the current case. Bottom line: it's likely to be allowed, but not certain.

Comment: @JerryCoffin (On an unrelated note, my example is actually not relevant, sorry. However, just consider Krauss's, or any other in which `initializer_list<…>`'s instantiation is not necessitated through the instantiation of a [member] function template/temploid or static data member temploid, because the PoIs of these are after the namespace scope definition, not before it)

Comment: @JerryCoffin Of course we aren't certain. We also weren't "certain" after C++11 that calling some `std::function<void()>` was intended to be well-formed and the relevant sections to be resolved. Would it have been sensible to advise programmers against using `function<void()>`? Is it sensible to advise against usage of `initializer_list` inside a class definition with that class as the argument because we aren't certain that LWG just forgot to add the wording? In this case, the intention assuredly was that such usage is fine, although I can't give you a 100%.

Comment: Columbo, @JerryCoffin: Do you know of any updates or further discussion re this? The link given still says the DR is just "New".

Answer (score 2):

§ [res.on.functions]/2:

> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>   [...]
>   (2.5) - if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for that component.

I see no such specific allowance for `initializer_list` to be instantiated over an incomplete type (in either §[dcl.init.list] or §[support.init.list], at least as of N4296).