# Storing a nested braced initlist doesn't work in gcc and msvc (but in clang)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, nested-lists, initializer-list

I'm storing an `initializer_list` of some datatype for temporary processing. It works like this: The user can input a nested braced lists into the processing function to easily clarify the structure. Each object `topic` then stores the initializer list until the end uf the full expression, which is after processing through the function `register_topics`, which accesses the initlist and puts the topics somewhere else (maybe a vector). Now this code works fine from clang86 > 10. But it fails to compile in gcc86 12 and msvc. Am I doing something wrong or is it the compilers? How can I adapt my code to make it work across all the major compilers?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:33,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:33,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Cinitializer_list%3E%0A%0Astruct+topic%0A%7B%0A++++using+callback_type+%3D+void+(*)()%3B%0A++++topic()+%3D+default%3B%0A++++topic(const+char*+name,+callback_type+fn,+std::initializer_list%3Ctopic%3E+init+%3D+%7B%7D)%0A++++++++:+++name_%7Bname%7D,%0A++++++++++++fn_%7Bfn%7D,%0A++++++++++++init_%7Binit%7D%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++const+char*+name_%3B%0A++++callback_type+fn_%3B%0A++++std::initializer_list%3Ctopic%3E+init_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avoid+register_topics(topic+topic_structure)%0A%7B%0A++++/*+we!%27re+doing+something+here+with+topic_structure+%0A++++where+we+need+to+access+the+initializer_lists+that+have%0A++++been+temporarily+stored+by+our+topic+objects+*/%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++auto+lambda1+%3D+%5B%5D()+-%3E+void+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0A++++register_topics(%7B+%22hello%22,+lambda1,+%7B+%7B%22hello2%22,+lambda1%7D,+%7B+%22hello3%22,+lambda1+%7D%7D+%7D)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.66057441253264,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-O2+-Wall%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:43.35736354273945,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:56.64263645726055,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.33942558746736,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <initializer_list>

struct topic
{
    using callback_type = void (*)();
    topic() = default;
    topic(const char* name, callback_type fn, std::initializer_list<topic> init = {})
        :   name_{name},
            fn_{fn},
            init_{init}
    {
        
    }

    const char* name_;
    callback_type fn_;
    std::initializer_list<topic> init_;
};

void register_topics(topic topic_structure)
{
    /* we're doing something here with topic_structure 
    where we need to access the initializer_lists that have
    been temporarily stored by our topic objects */
}

int main()
{
    auto lambda1 = []() -> void {};

    register_topics({ "hello", lambda1, { {"hello2", lambda1}, { "hello3", lambda1 }} });
}
```

Error (gcc 86 12)

```
<source>: In constructor 'topic::topic(const char*, callback_type, std::initializer_list<topic>)':
<source>:11:13: error: could not convert '{init}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::initializer_list<topic>'
   11 |             init_{init}
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |             |
      |             <brace-enclosed initializer list>
```

Comment: Simple solution: `init_{init}`-> `init_(init)`.

Comment: Here is the reduced version: https://godbolt.org/z/TM7s39Kf5

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That works indeed thank you! Why is that though?

Comment: The code has **undefined behavior** pre C++20. See related/dupe: [Incomplete types and initializer_list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34659923/incomplete-types-and-initializer-list) and also [std::map::reverse_iterator doesn't work with C++20 when used with incomplete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73343631/stdmapreverse-iterator-doesnt-work-with-c20-when-used-with-incomplete-typ)

Comment: @glades - "_Why is that though?_" The same resone why you cannot do this `std::initializer_list<topic> init_{init}` The initializer-list shall contains objects of type `topic` _not_ another initializer list

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Or you know, maybe you need to define the member `init_` as `std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<topic>> init_;`

Comment: @John That's one way to solve this specific problem. *But* initializer lists are rather temporary, and copying an initializer list copies the initializer list object but not the underlying array objects. So once the constructor function returns the data in the list will become invalid.

Comment: @John But shouldn't that invoke the default copy constructor of the initlist?

Comment: @JasonLiam Interesting, I always found it suspicious that my initlists worked with incomplete types when other types didn't allow that

Comment: @glades Yes, with undefined behavior there is no guarantee to what might happen. The program may seem to work.